# Как лучше прописывать свойства в классе React?

Tags: reactjs, классы, ecmascript-6

Подскажите пожалуйста... тут, наверное, дело в теории... как лучше прописывать в React свойства классам, а также их функции?

Я часто вижу, что свойства обозначают в самом рендере, типа такого:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {a, b} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{a}</p>
                <p>{b}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App a="hello" b="world" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Пусть, к примеру, это `statefull Class`, и есть смысл в прописи именно класса, а не простого конструктора... не в этом вопрос...
Если это класс, то создаваемый экземпляр, похоже, не будет иметь своих свойств `this.a` и `this.b`: но имеет свой `this.props` (с `а` и `в` внутри).
А функция `render` это `prototype.render()`, в которой наши свойства вычисляются из `props` и возвращается `JSX` обьект. Тоесть, экземпляр не имеет своих свойств, кроме `props`... а функцию он берет из prototype... 
Вроде бы лучше делать экземпляр более полноценным, делая его ключевые свойства открытыми типа:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.a = props.a;
        this.b = props.b;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.a}</p>
                <p>{this.b}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Тогда prototype function `render` выполняет только главную роль в возврате JSX объекта (а не, в добавок, получении свойств из props., а сам экземпляр имеет свои открытые целевые свойства, а не пустой объект (кроме props)... 
Экземпляр возвращает JSX объект лишь при запуске render()...

Answer (score 0):

Потому что твой вариант не работает. Если очень захотеть, то можно обернуть получение значения в getter, но это абсолютно бессмысленная затея.

```js
class FromProps extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>
  }
}

class FromConstructor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.value = this.props.value
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.value}</div>
  }
}

class FromGetter extends React.Component {
  get value() {
    return this.props.value
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.value}</div>
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: Math.random() }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FromProps value={this.state.value} />
        <FromConstructor value={this.state.value} />
        <FromGetter value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.setState({ value: Math.random() }), 1000)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main id=root></main>
```

Comment: @VKomolov, ладно, похоже, я только на первую часть вопроса ответил. Ответ на вторую - можно делать bind в конструкторе вместо инстансных функций: `class { construcntor(props) { super(props); this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this); } onclick() { ... } }`. А оценок я никаких не ставил.

Comment: @VKomolov, 2 минуса - ну и что? Мелочь же.

Comment: Спасибо, Qwertiy...
не мелочь... неправильно формирую мысль... не предполагаю, что примеры могут быть приняты за "чистую монету"...
Всем надо "чистые" и практические решения, а не растекания мысли, типа почему мы не прописываем методы в prototype. Всех устраивает создание свойства в Классе в виде функции...
даже если this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)....
работает же...
Еще раз спасибо, Qwertiy.... че то у меня депресс :)

Comment: @meticulous, может ты лучше отдельным вопросом задашь про методы, а то как-то слишком объёмно получается? Отвечу там.

Comment: приветствую, @Qwertiy, высылаю развернутый вопрос... вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997330/%D0%92%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-react-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-this)

Comment: @meticulous, убрал вторую часть и вопроса, а на новый вечером отвечу.

Comment: `Потому что твой вариант не работает.` - это не совсем правда. Все отработает, просто при изменении пропсов компонент не будет ре-рендерится. Ведь даже в твоем ответе содержится аналогичный вариант, как из вопроса

Comment: @Klimenkomud, именно это и называется "не работает". Я же не говорил, что он "не компилируется".

Comment: @Qwertiy Так оно работает, ошибок не будет, скрипт не свалится, просто сам функционал пропсов не будет работать как ожидается (визуально, они "пробросятся" только раз).