# Внутренние методы Класса в React с привязкой THIS

Tags: reactjs, классы, ecmascript-6

вопрос чисто теоретический:
Когда мы прописываем метод в Классе обычным образом типа: `handle(){}`, то он прописывается в prototype Класса. И это как бы рекомендуемая прототипная практика: в конструкторах содержать свойства, а в prototype общие методы для всех экземпляров.

Если мы взглянем на создание Класса в React, то такого типа методы также прописываются в prototype... а чтобы не затерять контекст рекомендуют юзать привязку метода в конструкторе... типа: `this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);`

Также используют и стрелочные функции декларируя ее типа: `handle = () => {};`

ВОПРОС:

`this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);` является свойством, значение которого является прототипная функция этого же Класса, привязанная к THIS этого же Класса... ведь так?

`handle = () => {};` просто является свойством Класса (прописанная вне Конструктора экземпляров), значением которого есть функция, хоть и стрелочная, без своего контекста... ведь так?

В одном случае мы в свойствах Конструктора имеем ссылку на собственную прототипную функцию, но привязанную к контексту...
Стрелочная функция Конструктора тупо прописана в свойствах...

Насколько рациональным и правильным будет все же придерживаться прототипного прописания функции? А если она попадает под чужой контекст типа события: onClick, то на событии юзать стрелочную функцию, типа: onClick={() => this.handle()}, чтобы не замазывать контекст...

Конечно, если прототипную функцию мы будем пробрасывать через props другому компоненту, то тут без `this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);`, как я понял, не обойтись...

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clicked: 0
        };
        this.btnHandlePrt = this.btnHandlePrt.bind(this); //ЭТО СВОЙСТВО-ФУНКЦИЯ
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>By prototype function binded in the Constructor
                    <button onClick={this.btnHandlePrt}>Click</button>
                </p>
                <p>By Arrow Function in Class
                    <button onClick={this.btnHandleArrow}>Click</button>
                </p>
                <p>By prototype function with no bindings.
                    <button onClick={() => this.btnHandlePrtFree()}>
                       Click
                    </button>
                </p>

                {/*<button onClick={this.btnHandleArrow}>click</button>*/}
                <span>Clicked: {this.state.clicked}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }

    btnHandlePrt() { ///ЭТО ФУНКЦИЯ в prototype
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                clicked: prevState.clicked + 1
            }
        })
    }
    btnHandlePrtFree() { ///ЭТО ФУНКЦИЯ в prototype
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                clicked: prevState.clicked + 1
            }
        })
    }
    btnHandleArrow = () => { //ЭТО СВОЙСТВО-ФУНКЦИЯ
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                clicked: prevState.clicked + 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Весь сыр-бор - лишь в прототипном прописании методов Класса и избавлении от привязок методов в свойствах Класса... хотя, как я говорил, без этого не обойтись, если приходится пробрасывать метод в пропсы других компонентов...

В Классе - свойства, методы - в prototype Класса. Хотя все равно рендерим JSX объект... Но все же, как Вы думаете, стоит, не задумываясь шлепать func = ()=> {}???

С уважением,

Comment: вот текста вроде много, но что конкретно ты спрашиваешь - непонятно

Comment: @Grundy, вроде всё понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, опиши в двух словах. типа что лучше использовать bind или arrow function?

Comment: @Grundy, я вечером отвечу. Мы вот тут обсуждали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/996520/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-react/996546?noredirect=1#comment1685090_996546

Comment: @Grundy, приветствую... я заметил, что трудно объясняюсь...
И bind, и arrow function создают СВОЙСТВО в Классе в виде функции...
В прототипной практике методы прописывают в prototype Класса для новых экземпляров... а не в свойства Класса... ведь так???
Это чисто теоретический вопроc.

Comment: Стоит ли придерживаться прописания методов именно в prototype, как в примере с btnHandlePrtFree() ???
А байндить контекст лишь для отправки метода через пропсы другому компоненту...
Классам - свойства, а методы экземплярам через prototype...

Comment: Проблема с контекстом для прототипных функций Класса (пример: btnHandlePrtFree() ) можно решать стрелочной функцией на ивенте, не запирая контекст... вот я о чем... 
Как я вижу, большинство не заморачиваются и юзают func = () => {}
Но насколько это верно в прототипном подходе...

Comment: @meticulous, формально ответ: как тебе больше нравится, работает и так и так.

Comment: @Grundy, это понятно :))
но ведь мы в Класс загоняем МЕТОД...
когда можно оставлять Класс чистым только со свойствами... и лишь в случае передачи метода в пропсы другим компонентам, можно использовать привязку контекста...
Насчет стрелочных функций в виде свойств Класса я вообще не говорю :)

Comment: часто юзают прототипный подход с императивным мышлением :))

Comment: @meticulous, _но ведь мы в Класс загоняем МЕТОД... когда можно оставлять Класс чистым только со свойствами... и лишь в случае передачи метода в пропсы другим компонентам, можно использовать привязку контекста..._ - так никто не мешает делать именно так :) Привязывать контекст, только когда это действительно нужно.

Comment: УРА! :)
@Grundy, согласен, что наблюдается повсеместное использование стрелочных функций и привязки собственного прототипного метода к собственному контексту экземпляра Класса? :)

Comment: Интересно подождать рекомендаций @Qwertiy...
Если то, что мы обсуждаем - верно.., то стрелочные функции в Классе в виде свойства - это не каминфо...
А привязка контекста в Конструкторе - это лишь исключение для проброса метода в чужой мир...
Юзаем чисто прототипные методы Класса...согласны???

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну и где? :)

Comment: Кстати, можно пробрасывать **btnHandlePrtFree()** в нижние компоненты и без привязки к THIS типа: `<Kid onClick={() => this.btnHandlePrtFree()} />`
Хотя вот [здесь](https://learn-reactjs.ru/basics/handling-events) говорится, что тогда Kid будет делать дополнительную перерисовку... поэтому при пробросе колбека в props лучше функцию привязать в Конструкторе к THIS. Интересно тогда почему происходит ПЕРЕРИСОВКА нижнего Компонента? Как это механически происходит... :))

Comment: @meticulous, посмотри исходники реакта.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, ты не совсем правильно трактуешь то, что делает `bind`. `bind` не создает свойство в Классе, а просто определяет контекст этой функции, "каррирует" туда `this`.  Ровно как и стрелочная функция не является свойством в Классе, а является методом, просто не имеет собственного контекста выполнения, и поэтому `this` в нем является тем, что находится выше(для реакта - экземпляр класса). И, сейчас будет взрыв мозгов: в JS, классы - просто синтаксический сахар поверх прототипов, и по факту, каждый класс - просто прототип, так что все методы в классе являются методами в прототипе.

Соответственно, с точки зрения "как правильнее придерживаться прототипного подхода" - одинаково.

Другой интересный момент состоит в том, что функции использующие `bind` работают гораздо быстрее стрелочных, + быстрее обрабатываются компилятором(т.е. `babel/typescript/anything else`). Видел одну статью с бенчмарками, к сожалению ссылку где-то потерял :(

Но даже при том, что стрелочные функции работают медленнее - скорость их работы всё равно высока, а выглядят они куда лаконичнее и не требуют дополнительной передачи контекста, так что лично я считаю, что для повышения качества кода лучше использовать именно стрелочные функции

Comment: приветствую... благодарен за аргументы.
Позволь все же продолжить эту, скорее, беседу по теории...
Насчет сахара я полностью согласен, что, по сути дела, Конструктор Класса прописывает свойства Класса, а методы вне Конструктора - прописываются в prototype...
Рассмотрим код:
class Something {
    constructor(some) {
        this._some = some;
        this.initData = this.initDataProto.bind(this);
    }
    initDataProto() {
        return this._some;
    }
    getData = () => {
        return this._some;
    }
}

Comment: Прав ли я, если скажу, что в случае с bind:
мы прописываем вне Конструктора метод initDataProto, уходящий в prototype Класса, а потом декларируем этот метод в Конструкторе, привязывая его к контексту this...
this.initData = this.initDataProto.bind(this);
Мы декларируем функцию, а значит присваиваем Классу свойство в виде декларированного метода...
И воспринимается это, как СВОЙСТВО Класса, значением которого является метод, привязанный к контексту...
Тоесть, сначала мы создаем прототипный метод, а потом в догонку мы еще создаем свойство в Конструкторе в виде каррированной функции :)

Comment: В случае со стрелочной функцией:
мы также наблюдаем декларирование метода, который не виден в prototype, а находится в виде свойства, декларирующего метод без контекста. В итоге в консоли я вижу 3 свойства:
getData: () => {
 return this._some;
 }
initData: ƒ ()
_some: "some"


А в prototype, как и ожидается, initDataProto: ƒ initDataProto()

Я ни в коем случае не подвергаю сомнению best practices... 
Это лишь просто рассуждение на тему прописания методов Класса именно в prototype...

Comment: Если вне Конструктора Класса взять да прописать prop = 'something' (там где пишем методы), то получим очередное свойство, прописанное вне Конструктора и видное в консоли, как свойство Класса prop: "something"...
Я полагаю, что прописание стрелочной функции ощущает ту же механику - прописание свойства в виде декларированной стрелочной функции...
Как Вы думаете?